# What encryption would be used if ECC is disabled in JDK 1.7 JVM?

Tags: java, encryption, jvm

We've been bitten by this Java bug

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7016078

And the solution we've applied is adding this argument *-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.enableECC=false* to the JVM.

Now the question is, what encryption will be used if ECC is disabled by the above parameter? Apparently it would fall back to RSA I believe. If such is the case, during negotiation which is where ECC will be used, what would be used in that place instead of ECC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see this by using `-Djava.net.debug=ssl`, under the section ClientHello

Normal:

Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]

With `-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.enableECC=false`

Cipher Suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]

(This is on Windows - I noticed on OpenJDK on Red Hat, it made no difference)

Comment: I added this flag to my JVM but am not able to see any such log printed :( Does it gets printed when the JVM starts up or should any SSL related activity be done to get this printed ?

Comment: Actually it worked with -Djavax.net.debug=ssl when I did a SSL activity. Thanks @artbristol for your help